# Angular2 DI with ES2016 decorators?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-2016

This is the closest I've gotten [on github](https://github.com/iksose/base-express-angular-postgres/tree/ES2015/client/app/todo)

My service is

`@Injectable()
export class TodoService {}`

But I'm unsure how to inject it into my component using ES2016 decorators. Is it even possible, or are the decorators Typescript-specific? I know in TS there's a `emitDecoratorMetadata` option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use [providers](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.44/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/directives.ts#L665) or [viewProviders](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.44/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/directives.ts#L873) to "provide" service to the component:
2. Inject service into component constructor specifying parameters types:

```js
@Component({
  // ...
  providers: [TodoService]
})
class TodoComponent() {

  constructor(todoService: TodoService) {
    this.todoService = todoService;
  }
}
```

or using `Inject` parameter decorator.

```js
@Component({
  // ...
  providers: [TodoService]
})
class TodoComponent() {

  constructor(@Inject(TodoService) todoService) {
    this.todoService = todoService;
  }
}
```

Parameter decorators are not part of the ES2016 (you can consider it as TypeScript specific). But they can be [added to the standard later](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1301#issuecomment-142532128)).

If you really want to use ES6/ES7, use static getter for `parameters`:

```js
@Component({
  // ...
  providers: [TodoService]
})
class TodoComponent() {

  static get parameters() {
    return [[TodoService]]; // you can also return just [TodoService]
  }

  constructor(todoService) {
    this.todoService = todoService;
  }
}
```

Also, I recommend you to read [this article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html) to better understand angular2 Dependency Injection.

Comment: So both of those implementations are Typescript specific? There's no way to use ES2016 decorators (which doesn't include parameter decorators, thanks for the link)?

Comment: @iksose I've added example for ES6/ES7